# How to fetch multiple Redis list from a single command

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am new to Redis. 
I want to fetch multiple lists from their keys.

My code is as follows

```
RedisValue[] valuelist= null;

for each( string item in Key_array){


valuelist = db.ListRange("item");
// do some calculations with the valuelist items.


}
```

As I am aware, this code has O(n) time complexity. Is there any way to execute this fetching from a single query.

I am using C# with StackExchange.Redis.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43359695/how-to-read-multiple-sets-stored-on-redis-using-some-command-or-lua-script?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Thanks, But that answer is for Sets. In my case, I want to retrieve multiple Lists

Answer (score 5):

Use `StackExchange.Redis.Extensions` package

retrieve multiple object with single roundtrip

```
var cachedData = db.GetAll<T>(new {"key1","key2","key3"});
```

more information is here https://github.com/imperugo/StackExchange.Redis.Extensions

I hope this help you